# Unable to install jekyll 3.8.6 using Ruby 2.6.3 on Windows 10

Tags: installation, jekyll

I get this error installing Jekyll:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>c:\Ruby263-x64\bin\gem.cmd install jekyll --version 3.8.6
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /O=Humana Inc./CN=Humana Enterprise Root CA 3 to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /O=Humana Inc./CN=Humana Enterprise Root CA 3 to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /O=Humana Inc./CN=Humana Enterprise Root CA 3 to your local trusted store
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jekyll' (= 3.8.6), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /O=Humana Inc./CN=Humana Enterprise Root CA 3 to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /O=Humana Inc./CN=Humana Enterprise Root CA 3 to your local trusted store
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to write a comment however, try visiting https://rubygems.org to see if your browser prompts you to install/trust their SSL certificate.